# Best thresholding technique for seperate a ECG graph from ECG grid?

Tags: image, image-processing, threshold

There are two type of image thresholding techniques.
1.adaptive thresholding
2.Global thresholding

what is the best algorithm we can use to seperate a ECG line from ECG grid?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please look [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1061/748) for one possible solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using MATLAB, I would go about doing the following :

1. I=im2double(rgb2gray(Img));
2. imhist(I); %%Shows you the histogram of the image. From the histogram, you can get an idea of the threshold to choose.
3. BW=im2bw(I,thr); %thr is  the threshold level.
4. Play around with the imerode, imdilate and other morphological functions to separate the ECG from the background grid.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Python, I would go about doing the following :

cv2.Canny() can be used this way to detect and remove gridlines in an ECG-image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ECG_image = cv2.imread("image001.png")
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.imshow(ECG_image)
```

[image]

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(ECG_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_edges = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 800, 800, apertureSize=3)
```

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.imshow(img_edges)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You will have to experiment with the parameters in the Canny-function in order to fit the function to your need.